# Indirect Variable References in fish-shell

Tags: fish

How can I do indirect variable references in fish script?

So I have a variable `$var1` which contains the name of another variable `$var2`.
No I want to now what is inside `$var2`.

In bash I could use `value = ${!var1}` in other shells the quite ugly `eval "value=\"\${$var1}\""` is unfortunately needed. But I somehow can't get to work anything in fish.

P.S. I need that because I source files which are defining commands which are given to a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `$$var1`.

Keep in mind that slices are used inside-out, so `$$var1[1]` is all elements of the variable named by the first element of `var1`.

Comment: Tried that, didn't worked... so it turned out I misunderstood `$_` and the content of the var was wrong (but similar, so it looked okay for me). So i thought that is wrong, since i found nothing on it. Anyway, this is the right answer and may help other people. It is also way cleaner than in other shells. Thank you for your time!

Comment: So why don't you just ask your actual question?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. That was my actual question, it turned out it was not my only problem. But to be sure how the indirect reference works made me search on the right place. So I am all fine, you helped my a lot it works now and this question should be here on SO as it is. (The other problem was trivial and not interesting for SO).

Comment: On fishshell 3.5, $$var does not work for me.  Rather I get a warning 

`fish: $$ is not the pid. In fish, please use $fish_pid.`

for example:

`set $x "\$HOME"
echo $x
  --> $HOME

echo $$x
  --> fish: $$ is not the pid. In fish, please use $fish_pid.`

Comment: You only need the variable *name* as the value, and you don't use `$` when setting. `set x HOME; echo $$x`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Sorry but the extra $ was just my typo. This still has same error for me: ```set x “\$HOME”; echo $$x``` - use of $HOME in this example is a contrivance just to create an indirect expansion scenario. $HOME is escaped so that $x takes the var name at setting time, rather than expand value at set time.

Comment: I think I understand your comment now and I can get your correct version of my scenario to work. Thanks!